# How to run a shell script file from python code in an ec2 instance in aws?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

I have some python code for preprocessing/training . I have a shell script file (sample code below) that i would like to run from my python script.how can i run this script from my python main.py file ? also what file permissions should the my shell script needs to have?

main.py

```
import os
import subprocess
import venv

venv.create('a_venv', with_pip=True) 

##invoke shell script here
```

somescript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "how to run this"
....do something
```

Comment: **Side-note:** The fact that it is running on an Amazon ECC2 instance is not relevant. EC2 instances run the same operating system as a 'normal' computer.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - one thing i noticed one difference, running same code in ec2 is that , in my pyhon code , i create a virtual environment with venv library and the flag with_pip is set to true( updated code in my question) , in ec2 i dont see pip installed where  as in my local machine , the pip is available under my virtual environment created with my code. i can' t find out why is that